# How can Python keep generating a random list of numbers until it equals to a certain made-up list?

Tags: python

Background: I was trying to create a code that would make Python generate a pattern from a 3 x 3 grid of dots, such that once a dot is chosen, the next dot can only be adjacent to it, and that no dot can be used twice. The following code is my input into Python for generating a 5-dot pattern for a 3 x 3 grid.

```
import random
x_arr=[]
y_arr=[]
def addTolist(m,n):
    x_arr.append(m)
    y_arr.append(n)
grid = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]        #rows of dots from top to bottom
dot = random.choice(range(1,10))        #random dot from the grid is chosen
for i in range(3):                         
    for j in range(3):
        if dot == grid[i][j]:
            x = i
            y = j 
            break
num = [dot]           
for i in range(5):                      # loop 5 times
    print('dot:',dot)
    # every time empty the list 
    neighbours = []
    x_arr=[]
    y_arr=[]
    #choosing only the adjacent numbers (neighbours) to the current dot
    if y-1 >= 0:
        neighbours.append(grid[x][y-1])
        addTolist(x,y-1)
        if x+1 < 3:
            neighbours.append(grid[x+1][y-1])
            addTolist(x+1,y-1)
        if x-1 >= 0:
            neighbours.append(grid[x-1][y-1])
            addTolist(x-1,y-1)
    if x-1 >= 0:
        neighbours.append(grid[x-1][y])
        addTolist(x-1,y)
        if y+1 < 3:
            neighbours.append(grid[x-1][y+1])
            addTolist(x-1,y+1)
    if y+1 < 3:
        neighbours.append(grid[x][y+1])
        addTolist(x,y+1)
        if x+1 < 3:
            neighbours.append(grid[x+1][y+1])
            addTolist(x+1,y+1)
    if x+1 < 3:
        neighbours.append(grid[x+1][y])
        addTolist(x+1,y)
    dot = random.choice(neighbours)
    while dot in num:                   
        dot = random.choice(neighbours)
    num.append(dot)
    position = neighbours.index(dot)
    x = x_arr[position]
    y = y_arr[position]
```

Output:

```
('dot:', 6)
('dot:', 2)
('dot:', 3)
('dot:', 5)
('dot:', 7)
```

Is there any way that I can keep generating these patterns (without repetition) until it equals to the pattern [1,2,6,9,8] and find how many trials it took to get to this pattern [1,2,6,9,8]? I assume that I would have to get the output into a single list first, but I have been struggling to do so. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you want to create in each step a list of the form [x,x,x,x,x] where x is a random number, and compare it with [1,2,3,9,8]?

Comment: you have to check from 1st random number if it is equal to the 1 element in the list if not you have to generate another number , you have to follow till the pattern in not form.

Comment: @orestiss Yes! That's exactly it. Do you think it is possible (given the conditions I described)?

Comment: Is it always like [1,2,6,9,8] or sequence is not important?

Comment: @KalpeshDusane I am using [1,2,6,9,8] as the pattern that Python must try to guess, so the sequence here would be important.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think it would work:

```
import random
x_arr=[]
y_arr=[]
index = 0
pattern = [1,2,6,9,8]
def addTolist(m,n):
    x_arr.append(m)
    y_arr.append(n)
grid = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]        #rows of dots from top to bottom
dot = random.choice(range(1,10))        #random dot from the grid is chosen
guess = 1
while dot!= pattern[index]:
    print("Wrong guess",dot)
    guess += 1
    dot = random.choice(range(1,10)) 
for i in range(3):                         
    for j in range(3):
        if dot == grid[i][j]:
            x = i
            y = j 
            break
num = [dot]  
print('dot:',dot)
for i in range(4):                     
    index +=1
    # every time empty the list 
    neighbours = []
    x_arr=[]
    y_arr=[]
    #choosing only the adjacent numbers (neighbours) to the current dot
    if y-1 >= 0:
        neighbours.append(grid[x][y-1])
        addTolist(x,y-1)
        if x+1 < 3:
            neighbours.append(grid[x+1][y-1])
            addTolist(x+1,y-1)
        if x-1 >= 0:
            neighbours.append(grid[x-1][y-1])
            addTolist(x-1,y-1)
    if x-1 >= 0:
        neighbours.append(grid[x-1][y])
        addTolist(x-1,y)
        if y+1 < 3:
            neighbours.append(grid[x-1][y+1])
            addTolist(x-1,y+1)
    if y+1 < 3:
        neighbours.append(grid[x][y+1])
        addTolist(x,y+1)
        if x+1 < 3:
            neighbours.append(grid[x+1][y+1])
            addTolist(x+1,y+1)
    if x+1 < 3:
        neighbours.append(grid[x+1][y])
        addTolist(x+1,y)
    if pattern[index] not in neighbours:     # if wrong Pattern is entered
        print("Wrong Pattern can not generate",pattern[index] , "After",pattern[index-1])
        break
    dot = random.choice(neighbours)
    guess += 1 
    while dot != pattern[index]:            # for checking pattern
        print("Wrong guess",dot)
        dot = random.choice(neighbours)
        guess += 1
    print('dot:',dot)
    num.append(dot)
    position = neighbours.index(dot)
    x = x_arr[position]
    y = y_arr[position]
print("Total guess :",guess)
```

Output:

```
Wrong guess 3
Wrong guess 7
Wrong guess 5
Wrong guess 8
Wrong guess 5
Wrong guess 4
dot: 1
dot: 2
Wrong guess 4
Wrong guess 1
Wrong guess 5
Wrong guess 1
Wrong guess 1
dot: 6
Wrong guess 8
Wrong guess 8
dot: 9
dot: 8
Total guess : 18
```

**Modifications:**

- Instead of checking unique variable , I am checking for pattern, So I
  take `pattern` list.
- I am checking for `range(4)` instead of `5` because 1st number is
  already generated and so why waste computing 6th random number when
  we are not even printing it.
- I take `guess` variable to keep track of number of guesses.

**Note :** I am checking for if pattern is wrong then it will print wrong pattern .

For example: if pattern =`[1,2,3,9,8]`   it will give output as:

```
Wrong guess 7
Wrong guess 4
dot: 1
Wrong guess 5
Wrong guess 4
Wrong guess 5
dot: 2
Wrong guess 4
dot: 3
Wrong Pattern can not generate 9 After 3
Total guess : 9
```

**Updated :** If you want to count whole sequence as the one guess then:

```
import random
x_arr=[]
y_arr=[]
index = 0
pattern = [1,2,6,9,8]
def addTolist(m,n):
    x_arr.append(m)
    y_arr.append(n)
guess = 0
while True :
    grid = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]        #rows of dots from top to bottom
    dot = random.choice(range(1,10))        #random dot from the grid is chosen
    for i in range(3):                         
        for j in range(3):
            if dot == grid[i][j]:
                x = i
                y = j 
                break
    num = [dot]  
    for i in range(4):    
        # every time empty the list 
        neighbours = []
        x_arr=[]
        y_arr=[]
        #choosing only the adjacent numbers (neighbours) to the current dot
        if y-1 >= 0:
            neighbours.append(grid[x][y-1])
            addTolist(x,y-1)
            if x+1 < 3:
                neighbours.append(grid[x+1][y-1])
                addTolist(x+1,y-1)
            if x-1 >= 0:
                neighbours.append(grid[x-1][y-1])
                addTolist(x-1,y-1)
        if x-1 >= 0:
            neighbours.append(grid[x-1][y])
            addTolist(x-1,y)
            if y+1 < 3:
                neighbours.append(grid[x-1][y+1])
                addTolist(x-1,y+1)
        if y+1 < 3:
            neighbours.append(grid[x][y+1])
            addTolist(x,y+1)
            if x+1 < 3:
                neighbours.append(grid[x+1][y+1])
                addTolist(x+1,y+1)
        if x+1 < 3:
            neighbours.append(grid[x+1][y])
            addTolist(x+1,y)
        dot = random.choice(neighbours)
        while dot in num :
            dot = random.choice(neighbours)
        num.append(dot)
        position = neighbours.index(dot)
        x = x_arr[position]
        y = y_arr[position]
    guess += 1
    if num == pattern :
        break
print("Total guess :",guess)
```

Output :

```
Total guess : 12
```

> **Note :** I don't recommended to use this method as sometimes it gives **total guess is 1** or most of the times it gives you **timeout**
>   because it is random it may happen that the required sequence may
>   never gets generated or running time exceeded. SO you can try put limit on the guesses like
>   instead of `while True` use `for c in range(50):` or what over range
>   you have to give.(And if timeout is coming run the code more number of
>   times till it gives you answer I tried 8-10 times before I got this
>   output)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am actually trying to find how many 'guesses' or 'trials' it will take for Python to guess the 1,2,6,9,8 pattern. So in your code, is there any way to show the number of trials needed to find my pattern? 

In addition (perhaps this is easier, if you have the time), is it possible to generate the total number of 5-dot patterns possible given all the conditions I explained in the question? Sorry for all the questions. Hope you are able to help.

Comment: @Shreya Basu I updated my answer you can check and if anything required let me know.

Comment: Wouldn't this assume that the dots are being guessed one by one? Rather than a sequence? For example, if Python guesses 1,2 first, and then guesses 4 for the third dot (instead of 6), it gets the pattern wrong. However, it might not guess 1 and 2 the first time again. It might guess 2,3 and then 6, for example.

Comment: @Shreya Basu I didn't understand ? can you explain more! sequence is one by one right?

Comment: @Shreya Basu I updated my answer.. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Let's say Python's first 5 guesses are 1,2,4,5,8. The first two dots are correct. However the rest of the pattern is incorrect. So, Python must try another pattern. This time it might be 4,1,2,5,7. Even though it got 2 of the numbers right the first time, the second time it guesses, it might not guess the same dots again (even if they are correct, since it doesn't know which is correct until the whole pattern is completely correct). Does that make a bit more sense? It is quite hard to explain.

Comment: @Shreya Basu .Yeah (but it increasese your run time).  check this Solution and Output :https://ideone.com/17r8sV . Does this helps?

Comment: I am not sure it is the solution I am looking for. It may be that this is too difficult. Is it easier if we let Python generate the patterns for, let's say, 100 times (and allow Python to repeat previous patterns it has generated) and then make it tell us how many times it guessed the right pattern (1,2,6,9,8)?

Comment: @Shreya Basu Yeah it  could be done just run the `for` loop instead of `while True:` till 100 times and instead of this statement `if num == pattern :` you can add it to some variable which is list of list (like `grid` variable) and at the end you can count the occurrence of the given pattern in that variable .